# error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘__complex__ double *’ from type ‘complex double’

Tags: python, c, arrays, pointers, types

## C Code

```
void myfunction(double complex *x,int i1,int i2,int NN)
{
  double complex *temp0;
  double complex *temp1;
  temp1=x[NN*i1+i2];
  x[NN*i1+i2]=temp0;
}
```

## Error

```
_fgt.c:381:12: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘__complex__ double *’ from type ‘complex double’
       temp1=x[NN*i1+i2];
            ^
_fgt.c:382:18: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘complex double’ from type ‘__complex__ double *’
       x[NN*i1+i2]=temp0;
                  ^
```

## Question

I am using pointers the wrong way, but I do not what to do to fix the code. I am trying to swap values in a 2D array pointed to by the pointer 'x', however my temporary pointers 'temp0' and 'temp 1' to hold values during the swap are type incompatible with the pointers to the 2D array 'x'. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you subscript the complex double pointer `x[NN*i1+i2]` you are dereferencing your pointer and getting an actual value, so here `temp0 = x[NN*i1+i2];` you're assigning a double complex value to a double complex pointer... kaboom.

Try this instead:

```
typedef complex<double> double_complex;

void myfunction(double_complex *x,int i1,int i2,int NN)
{
    // not a pointer anymore...
    double_complex temp0 = x[NN*i1+i2];
    x[NN*i1+i2] = temp0;
}
```

Comment: Your solution does not seem to work for me. I just checked the actual value temp0=-2097414484 and its address &temp0=-2097414480 and they are the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Here's a gist to show this: https://gist.github.com/MJWunderlich/bc4c71aa07e91db678df